# Form not populating in case of edit in React

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am using react with formik and yup.

```
import * as ReactImports from '../../../components/Imports/imports';
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Start of component
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { branchSchema } from 'schemas/branch';
function Branch() {  
  const { React, useState, useEffect, FilterMatchMode, FilterOperator, DataTable, Column, InputText, Button, Toolbar, Watch, useSelector, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label } = ReactImports;
  const [params,setParams] = useState({
    branch_name: "",
    branch_address: ""
  });

  // Global States
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [toggleBtn, setToggleBtn] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);
  // Other States
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [watch, isDisplay] = useState(false);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Model Stats
  const [branch_id, setBranchId] = useState();
  const [branches, setBranches] = useState([]);

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //  React Prime Start
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  const fStats = {
    global: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
    branch_name: {
      operator: FilterOperator.AND,
      constraints: [{ value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH }],
    },
    branch_address: {
      operator: FilterOperator.AND,
      constraints: [{ value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH }],
    },
  };
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(fStats);
  const [globalFilterValue, setGlobalFilterValue] = useState("");

  // Clear Filters
  const clearFilter = () => {
    initFilters();
  };

  const initFilters = () => {
    setFilters(fStats);
    setGlobalFilterValue("");
  };

  const onGlobalFilterChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let _filters = { ...filters };
    _filters["global"].value = value;

    setFilters(_filters);
    setGlobalFilterValue(value);
  };

  const renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <div className="flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h3 className="m-0">Branches</h3>
        <div>
          <span>
            {" "}
            <Button
              type="button"
              icon="pi pi-filter-slash"
              label="Clear"
              outlined
              onClick={clearFilter}
            />{" "}
          </span>
          <span className="p-input-icon-left">
            <i className="pi pi-search" />
            <InputText
              value={globalFilterValue}
              onChange={onGlobalFilterChange}
              placeholder="Keyword Search"
            />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const leftToolbarTemplate = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Button
          label="Add New"
          icon="pi pi-plus"
          className="p-button-success mr-2 p-button-sm"
          onClick={toggle}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  const rightToolbarTemplate = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Button
          type="button"
          icon="pi pi-file"
          rounded
          data-pr-tooltip="CSV"
          className="mr-2"
        />
        <Button
          type="button"
          icon="pi pi-file-excel"
          severity="success"
          rounded
          data-pr-tooltip="XLS"
          className="mr-2"
        />
        <Button
          type="button"
          icon="pi pi-file-pdf"
          severity="warning"
          rounded
          data-pr-tooltip="PDF"
          className="mr-2"
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  const header = renderHeader();
  function closed() {
    setParams({
      branch_name: "",
      branch_address: "",
    });
    setToggleBtn(false);
  }

  const serialNumber = (rowData, column) => {
    return column.rowIndex + 1;
  };

  function actions(rowData) {
    return (
      <>
        <Button
          icon="pi pi-pencil"
          className="p-button-rounded p-button-sm p-button-success mr-2"
          onClick={() => updateBranch(rowData.id)}
        />
        <Button
          icon="pi pi-trash"
          className="p-button-rounded p-button-danger"
          onClick={() => deleteBranch(rowData.id)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Positions Crud
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  const getBranches = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_BRANCHES_URL,
      {
        headers: { Authorization: token },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setBranches(data);
    }, 200);
    console.log(data);
  };

  const createBranch = async (values,action) => {
    isDisplay(true);
    if (!toggleBtn) {
      const response = await fetch(
        process.env.REACT_APP_BRANCHES_URL,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: token,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            branch_name: values.branch_name,
            branch_address: values.branch_address,
          }),
        }
      );

      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.status === 200) {
        setBranches([...branches, data.branches]);
        setToggleBtn(false);
        isDisplay(false);
        toggle();
        action.resetForm();
      }
      else{
        setToggleBtn(false);
        isDisplay(false);
      }
    } 
    else if (toggleBtn) {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BRANCHES_URL}/${branch_id}`,
        {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: token,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            branch_name: values.branch_name,
            branch_address: values.branch_address,
          }),
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.status === 200) {
        setBranches((prevBranches) => {
          const updatedBranches = prevBranches.map((branch) => {
            if (branch.id === branch_id) {
              return data.branches; // Replace the object with the updated object
            } else {
              return branch; // Return the original object for all other branches
            }
          });
          return updatedBranches;
        });
        setToggleBtn(false);
        isDisplay(false);
        toggle();
        action.resetForm();
      }
      else{
        setToggleBtn(false);
        isDisplay(false);
      }
    }
  };

  const deleteBranch = async (id) => {
    const shouldDelete = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (shouldDelete) {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BRANCHES_URL}/${id}`,
        {
          method: "DELETE",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: token,
          },
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.status === 200) {
        setBranches(branches.filter((branch) => branch.id !== id));
        //   setTimeout(() => {
        //     toast.success(`Province Has been Deleted successfully`, {
        //       position: "top-center",
        //       autoClose: 5000,
        //       hideProgressBar: false,
        //       closeOnClick: true,
        //       pauseOnHover: true,
        //       progress: undefined,
        //       theme: "light",
        //     });
        //   }, 2000);
      }
    }
  };

  function updateBranch(id) {
    const data = branches.find((cur) => {
      return id === cur.id;
    });
    if(data){
    console.log(data.branch_name);
    setParams({
      branch_name: data.branch_name,
      branch_address: data.branch_address,
    });
    setToggleBtn(true);
    setBranchId(data.id);
    toggle(); 
    }
    else
    {
      alert("not found");
    }

  }

  const { values, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, errors, touched } =
  useFormik({
    initialValues: params,
    validationSchema: branchSchema,
    validateOnChange: true,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    onSubmit: (values, action) => {
      createBranch(values,action);
    },
  });

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  useEffect(() => {
    getBranches();
  }, []);


  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  return (
    <>
      {/* Position Modal Start */}
      {/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} onClosed={closed}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Create Branch</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Form>
              <FormGroup floating>
                <Label>Branch Name</Label>
                <Input
                  id="branch_name"
                  name="branch_name"
                  placeholder="Branch Name"
                  type="text"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.branch_name}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
                 {touched.branch_name && errors.branch_name ? (
                      <p className="text-danger">{errors.branch_name}</p>
                    ) : null}
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup floating>
                <Label>Branch Address</Label>
                <Input
                  id="branch_address"
                  name="branch_address"
                  placeholder="Branch Address"
                  type="textarea"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.branch_address}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
                  {touched.branch_address && errors.branch_address ? (
                      <p className="text-danger">{errors.branch_address}</p>
                    ) : null}
              </FormGroup>
              {toggleBtn ? (
                <Button onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={watch}>
                  {" "}
                  <Watch
                    height="20"
                    width="50"
                    radius="48"
                    color="#4fa94d"
                    ariaLabel="watch-loading"
                    wrapperStyle={{}}
                    wrapperClassName=""
                    visible={watch}
                  />
                  Update Branch
                </Button>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Button onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={watch}>
                    {" "}
                    <Watch
                      height="20"
                      width="50"
                      radius="48"
                      color="#4fa94d"
                      ariaLabel="watch-loading"
                      wrapperStyle={{}}
                      wrapperClassName=""
                      visible={watch}
                    />{" "}
                    Create Branch
                  </Button>
                </>
              )}
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
      {/* Position Modal End */}
      {/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */}

      {/* Data table Start */}
      {/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
      <div className="datatable-doc-demo">
        <div className="card">
          <Toolbar
            className="mb-4"
            left={leftToolbarTemplate}
            right={rightToolbarTemplate}
          ></Toolbar>
          <DataTable
            value={branches}
            paginator
            scrollable
            className="p-datatable-customers"
            header={header}
            rows={10}
            size="normal"
            removableSort
            paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 50]}
            dataKey="id"
            rowHover
            loading={loading}
            filters={filters}
            filterDisplay="menu"
            responsiveLayout="scroll"
            globalFilterFields={["branch_name", "branch_address"]}
            emptyMessage="No positions found."
            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
          >
            <Column
              field="id"
              header="Sr.No"
              sortable
              style={{ minWidth: "14rem" }}
              body={serialNumber}
            />

            <Column
              field="branch_name"
              header="Branch Name"
              sortable
              filter
              filterPlaceholder="Search by position"
              style={{ minWidth: "14rem" }}
            />
            <Column
              field="branch_address"
              header="Branch Address"
              sortable
              filterField="branch_address"
              style={{ minWidth: "14rem" }}
              filter
              filterPlaceholder="Search by Position Details"
            />
            <Column />
            <Column />
            <Column header="Actions" body={actions} />
          </DataTable>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* End Data table */}
      {/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */}
    </>
  );
}

export default Branch;
```

This is my branches index where I show all branches. Now I have edit and delete button in front of each branch. When user clicks on the edit button, modal opens and I has the form. Now When I click on edit button, my execution goes to UpdateBranch function where I set the values of the form so that in case of edit, form gets pre-populated with the values but sadly it is not populated .
When I try to edit, form is not populating although I am setting the value here as well. I am doing same in other components and they are working fine.
[image]